# connecting spark to mongoDB in intellij IDEA

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying to follow this tutorial to connect spark and MongoDB in Intellij IDEA https://medium.com/@contactsunny/connect-apache-spark-to-your-mongodb-database-using-the-mongo-spark-connector-f826ffa0f991
and i found a problem in the first two steps the sparkConf won't work and i don't know why and the   `@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}") private val mongoDbConnectionUri = null` also

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using springboot too? Can you add your build.sbt too
If you are just reading from MongoDB with spark check this out https://koiralo.com/2020/06/21/how-to-read-and-write-data-from-mongodb-with-spark3/

Comment: First of all it seems that some double quotes that were copied with the code are wrong - delete them and re-enter in file. As for the import red highlighting - are you able to build project in IDE or in command line? Try deleting IDE **system** directory (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and re-import project via File | New | import from Existing Sources... action.

Comment: @koiralo i have added the build.sbt screenshot

Comment: @Andrey i don't know where is the mistake and i have checked the link and it didn't work either

Comment: @eyabaklouti Few things here, From built.sbt remove the duplicate spark-core dependency(one with 2.4.3). for your Spark code I have added a link please check that

Comment: done the only error that lasts in the line where   @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")

Comment: I am not sure why you are using the `@Value` annotation, remove it and add the mongodb url directly to the `mongoConnectionurl` variable

Comment: done , and no more errors thank you